# Do we need to initialize an array in Java?

Tags: java

I noticed that if I declare an array as:

```
int[] myarr = new int[10];
```

I can directly use `myarr[1] ++;` so that `myarr[1] = 1`. Does it mean that  in Java, we **do not** need to initialize the array and set each value as 0 by the following method?

```
for (int i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
     myarr[i] = 0;
}
```

I saw from some comments that the array may contain garbage values. If the array is an integer array, will it contain any garbage other than 0?

Comment: Do you *need* to initialize *anything* in Java?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Java, all array elements are automatically initialized to the default value.  For primitive numerical types, that's `0` or `0.0`.  For booleans, that's `false`.  For objects, that's `null`.

In other languages such as C++, the values in an uninitialized array are undefined.  Some compilers may initialize to 0/null similarly for security, and it's very bad practice to rely on this.  However, this behavior is well defined in Java and so it's perfectly okay to create a primitive array and trust that the values are 0.

Comment: See <https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2>

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2

Answer (score 6):

A newly-initialized `int[]` will be filled with zeros, by language specification.

Referring to [JLS §10.6 (Array Initializers)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> A one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and each component of the array is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).

Referring to [§4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
>   - For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (byte)0.
>   - For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (short)0.
>   - For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
>   - For type long, the default value is zero, that is, 0L.
>   - For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0f.
>   - For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.
>   - For type char, the default value is the null character, that is, '\u0000'.
>   - For type boolean, the default value is false.
>   - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

Answer (score 4):

no, all java arrays are filled with the appropriates type default value (0 for ints, 0.0 for doubles, null for references, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can't skip the *array* initialization but you don't have to initialize *each element* of the array. If you don't initialize an element in an array it works exactly like it would if you weren't initializing a member variable of that specific type: Java will initialize it with the type default value which is 0 for numerical primitive types (int, double, float...), *false* for booleans and null for objects (String included).

Answer (score -3):

No, it is compulsory to initialize an array in java.. When I was writing my programs, I didn't initialize my array and my compiler (jdk7) gave me an error like:

ArrayOne.java:4: Variable myArray may not have been initialized.

Thus failing my compilation.

Comment: That's not the same thing: it's saying that you never initialized the array *variable*, not its components. It'd do the same thing for non-array variables too. This requirement is called *definite assignment*.

Comment: In case you are wondering, this is described in [JLS section 4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5): "A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment))."

Comment: Thank you for the reference..