# System.out.println doesn't show text in console (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am writing a program which part is presented below:

```
public class Portal {

    private String name;
    private int[] positions;              // positions of "ship"
    private static int moves = 0;         // moves made by player to sink a ship
    public static int shot;               // the value of position given by player
    private int hits = 0;                 // number of hits
    private int maxSize = 4;              // max size of ship (the size will be randomized)
    int first;                            // position of 1st ship block
    int size;                             // real size of ship (randomized in setPortal method)

    public void checkIfHit(){
        for (int i : positions){
            if (i == shot){
                System.out.println("Hit confirmed");
                hits++;
            } else if (hits == positions.length){
                System.out.println("Sunk");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Missed it");
            }
        }
        moves++;
    }

    public void setPortal(){
        size = 1 + (int)Math.random()*maxSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
            if (i == 0){
                positions[i]= 1 + (int)Math.random()*positions.length;
                first = positions[i];
                System.out.println(positions[i]);
                continue;
            }
            positions[i]= first + 1;
            System.out.println(positions[i]);

        }
    }
}

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // write your code here
        Portal p1 = new Portal();
        p1.setPortal();
    }
}
```

code is split in two Java .class files.

The problem I'm dealing with is that using `p1.setPortal();` doesn't show up text in IntelliJ console. The program works though and returns 0.
I don't have such problem in another program when I've put `System.out.println` in method other than main (also in separate class file).
What may be the cause of such issue?

Comment: There is no guarantee that `setPortal` always prints something. `size` can be 1 and the `for` loop won't be entered.

Comment: That was precisely the main cause of the problem.
I've also fixed implementing positions to "more random" (I've improperly converted the type, and the outscore of "size" and "positions[0]" was always 0. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

It should properly throw an exception, because you forgot to initialize the integer array. 
Have a look at this thread: [Do we need to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295140/do-we-need-to-initialize-an-array-in-java/36295163)

The Java's default value is null for an integer array. So your for wont even loop trough. The only thing that wonders me is why there is no exception..

Comment: No, it should not because java has default constructors which will return null (NullPointerException), but thanks for -rep @spandey15

Comment: @spandey15 no it shouldn't because it's an instance variable which defaults to `null`. which leads to a `NullPointerException`